# Can sqlite-utils convert function select two columns for conversion?

Tags: sqlite

I'm using `sqlite-utils` to load a very large CSV into sqlite for later use in Datasette. In the CSV there are two columns, `likes` and `dislikes`, which I would like to use to create a third column `quality-score` by doing some simple math (likes / (likes + dislikes)). I need this quality score to be present in the database as it will be the basis for future queries - I can't just calculate the score on the fly.

The format of the `convert` function seems to take the db filename, the table name, the column name, then the Python function as a string - all as positional arguments. I've read through the documentation and I cannot seem to find anything that states two columns can be selected for a conversion.

Is it possible to use `sqlite-utils convert` to select more than one column for a conversion function?

Comment: Have you had a look at generated columns? https://www.sqlite.org/gencol.html

Comment: Thanks, generated columns would work, I'll just need to figure out if I can alter the table after the db is populated. My CSV doesn't have a header row and I have to run a few sqlite-utils transforms to get it into shape. Plus it doesn't appear sqlite-utils supports using a predefined schema for the CSV insert function. If I can add a generated column after the fact, this may work.

Comment: Im afraid I dont know sqllite, but I would suggest creating a small dummy table, load a minimal set of data and see if you can alter the table